# Formula to get text data

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on automating a report. I have around 50000 rows and 15 columns. I want a VBA code or Formula that will lookup the test data from sheet1 and get it on Sheet2. I have tried vlookup and index formulas, however, the code becomes very heavy and the macro does not work.

Please help.

Thank you,
Soni

Comment: Hi Soni, show us what you have so far..

Comment: Just sayin, Access can do this in a jiffy, import to Access, run a query, export back to Excel. Or if you don't have an Access license, even MySql with HeidiSQL, via CSV export.

Comment: @WhirlMind Yeah, that's the simple solution. ;) Much easier than just a bit of VBA.

Comment: A simple Index/Match formula should suffice - can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Whirl, I tried working it on access, but can you let me know how exactly do I work on it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to the difficulty vlookup has in identifying text vs values, like "1" vs 1.  Both may be wanted, but Excel views them as unique.

Something like the following may work:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($C1,$A:$B,2,0)),VLOOKUP(TEXT($C1,"@"),$A:$B,2,0),VLOOKUP($C1,$A:$B,2,0))
```

Comment: You could simplify this a little by using `=IFERROR()` instead of `=IF(ISERROR())` assuming you're using Excel 2007 or newer :)

Comment: Hi All, thank you for your response. Here is the formula =INDEX('Previous Resolve Report'!R3C20:R39496C20,MATCH('Resolve Report'!RC[-1],'Previous Resolve Report'!R4C19:R39496C19,0))"
    Range("X2").Select, but when I try to copy and paste special formulas it does not work at all. Please help!

Comment: If it is a working formula (which I question since the area ranges are not the same for the match vs. array), instead of copy pasting, I would suggest simply assigning the range, for example: `Range("X2:X5").FormulaR1C1 ="=INDEX('Previous Resolve Report'!R3C20:R39496C20,MATCH('Resolve Report'!RC[-1],'Previous Resolve Report'!R4C19:R39496C19,0))"`

Comment: thank you, is there any other way where I could get the data into my report faster. this takes atleast 10 mins and sometimes more.

Comment: thank you for your help, can you also let me know a way to paste special values after pasting the formula